# Getting Results of Get-ADComputer with Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, active-directory, invoke-command

I am working on a script that shall run on client (desktop) Windows machines that do not have any RSAT tools installed. The script will poll various things about the machine, and one of those I would like to include is the description of the machine in Active Directory. The ultimate goal is to save these into SQL for a pretty table.

I am able to get everything but the AD Description. This is what I am trying now:

```
$Computer = (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select -Expand Name) | Out-String

$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName domainController
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
param(
   [Parameter(Position=0)]
   $computer
)

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

write-host "the value of the passed parameter is $computer"

Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'DC=CONTOSO,DC=LOCAL' -Filter {Name -Like $computer} -Properties Description | Select -Expand Description

write-host "the name of this computer is $(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select -Expand Name)"

write-host $description

 } -ArgumentList $Computer
```

I know that the computer name is being passed, because the result of

```
write-host "the value of the passed parameter is $computer"
```

does indeed show the name of the computer I am passing. I know that the command is indeed running on the server because the result of

```
write-host "the name of this computer is $(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select -Expand Name)"
```

does indeed show the name of the server with ADUC installed. I know the command to pull the Description works on that server, because if I am connected to said server with RDP, I can run that command without issue.

I don't get any errors (and my $ErrorActionPreference is "Stop"), it just simply skips over the line of code like it's a comment.

Is there anything I am missing, or better yet a better way for me to pull the description of said computer?

Comment: Are you sure the Description property for the computer isn't empty?

Comment: Why are you running this command remotely? Just use `Get-ADComputer` on the domain controller?

Comment: I tried your `Get-ADComputer` line on a computer object that I know has the description field populated, and it did return the description.

Comment: @Persistent13 Correct, it is not empty - I should have been more clear that running the command while connected via RDP does in fact pull the expected description

Comment: @Jelphy What I am trying to do is have the script runnable on all client machines, so it can essentially 'probe' them and dump the data into SQL, for inventory tracking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to remote to request information from Active Directory. Here's a short example that doesn't even use the AD cmdlets:

```
$computerName = [Net.Dns]::GetHostName()

$searcher = [ADSISearcher] "(sAMAccountName=$computerName$)"
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(@("description"))
$searchResult = $searcher.FindOne()

"Computer description: {0}" -f $searchResult.Properties["description"][0]
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I was not aware there was a way to query in powershell without the RSAT cmdlets. This worked like a charm on the client machine (that does not have RSAT installed). Thank you very much!